# Is there a tool to migrate albums from Imgur to Picasa?

Tags: picasa-web-albums, imgur

I have some photo albums in Imgur and some in Picasa. But some people get strange 403 errors when following my Imgur links so I'd like to put everything on Picasa. And I would like not to have to download and upload everything by hand. Is there a tool somewhere that would automate the process?

Comment: Picasa Web Albums no longer exists. It has been subsumed into [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com) ([tag:google-photos]).

Answer (score -1):

There are tools you can use that would allow you to easily select a part of your page and upload them to locations or right click on the image and do this, but automating this is a no go. I can give you some links to some extensions to do this if needed.